Book where protagonist who repairs vases for a living is contacted by alien race
I am looking for the title of a science fiction book where the protagonist is a man who repairs vases as a job (and has a hard time making a living out of it) until they have a telepathic contact with an alien race from an unknown planet along with other people leading a dull life.

Galactic Pot-Healer by Philip K. Dick.

The Glimmung wants Joe Fernwright. Fernwright is a pot-healer - a repairer of ceramics - in a drably utilitarian future where such skills have little value. And the Glimmung? The Glimmung is a being that looks something like a gyroscope, something like a teenaged girl, and something like the contents of an ocean. What's more, it may be divine. And, like certain gods of old Earth, it has a bad temper.
What could an omnipresent and seemingly omnipotent entity want with a humble pot-healer? Or with the dozens of other odd creatures it has lured to Plowman's Planet? And if the Glimmung is a god, are its ends positive or malign? Combining quixotic adventure, spine-chilling horror, and deliriously paranoid theology, Galactic Pot-Healer is a uniquely Dickian voyage to alternate worlds of the imagination.


This answer is obviously correct. The book, published in 1969, is also notable for P.K. Dick imagining the "Conlingual Telephone" game, long before it was possible to translate one language to another by computer, and the absurdity of the resulting translations. I read the book before Babelfish or any other translation program was introduced, and I said to myself, "Yes, that's the way it would work." And that's the way it works.
